# Scraping websites with load more button using rvest

Tags: css, r, rvest

How can one scrape pages with load more button? There are 64 pages I need to scrape, but the following code provides the very first page.

```
crpyto_url <- read_html("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/")               
cryp_table <- html_nodes(crpyto_url, css = "table")
crypt_table <- html_table(cryp_table, fill = T) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I do not want to use `selenium` nor `BeautifulSoup` since I want this to be done programmatically. It looks this can be handled in Python; I hope there is a way in R to do so.

[image]

Comment: The button triggers a JavaScript event that loads more data. This event cannot be executed in rvest. You need to use a user agent with Java Script engine; there is no other way. Selenium / RSelenium would be an example. I don't understand why you cannot use it, because it is 100% programmable and requires no further user interaction when the script runs.

Comment: In the network tab of your browser's developer tools you may be able to see the API request that this JS Event triggers to get the additional data, then replicate that to make your custom request

Comment: As always with scraping, first check whether or not the site offers an API that may provide you with the data you need, like this: https://www.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/